# How can I iteratively remove each leaf DOM element in a page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i in jquery itirate the whole dom, delete element that have not children and so on and son on until the page is empty !
wouaaah

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: hehe are you making a cool bookmarklet..? :)

Comment: Why? Doing it element by element is very inefficient. `$('html').remove()` is much quicker (although just as pointless).

Comment: A test as in a homework test? If so, add the homework tag.

Comment: Please add the 'wouaaah' tag.

Comment: Edited the title to properly reflect the question. And +1 since I don't think it deserves a minus score.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$('*').each(function({
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: You aren't testing to make sure there are no child nodes.

Comment: am gonna try. But at the first time i jus would like to remove the element that have not child/children. Then the parents of those ellement will not have parents and so on

Answer (score 0):

try this, but it is not **iterate**:

```
var all = $('*');
while (all.length) {
    $(':empty').remove();
    all = $('*');
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, this IS an iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it... but I'm thinking something like this

```
$('body').children().each(function(){
    recursiveDestroyer(this);
});



function recursiveDestroyer(element){
    $(element).each(function(){
        if ($(element).children().size() == 0){
             $(element).hide();
        } else {
           return recursiveDestroyer($(element).children());  
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ah -- I'm too tired to fix it going to bed now, but i think this needs to be added and have the current loop placed within the if statement below

```
var hiddenCount = 0;
$(element).each(function(){
   if ($(this).is(":hidden")) { hiddenCount++; }
});

if (hiddenCount != $(element).size()){
  // insert the original $(element).each(.. function here
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: this seams logical, am gonna test and make a feadback

Comment: Let me know if it does haha I'm now curious :)

Comment: If you're trying to animate a page collapsing -- put setTimeout around the recursive step in the else statement.. and if u have a live page doig this leme see it unfold :p

Looking again at my code, I'm  not sure if it'll hide the parent after all children are hidden... I would add a piece after $(element).hide().. to check if the parent now has children that are all hidden.. if it does, hide the parent.